# Android Expandable List Child Layout not inflating correctly?

Tags: android, android-layout, expandablelistview

When i am expanding a child layout in my expandable list, it is forming differently everytime. I am using a linear layout with weight attributes so i don't think this should happen

No extra code is also present in `getChildView()` :-

```
    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean b, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    LayoutInflater cInflator = context.getLayoutInflater();
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = cInflator.inflate(R.layout.childrow, null);
    }
    return convertView;
}
```

**childrow.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/list_headings"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/list_headings_gradient"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/user_summary"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:layout_weight="40"
        android:textColor="@color/manage_users_heading_grey"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_weight="30" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/block"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:maxWidth="120dp"
        android:text="BLOCK"
        android:textColor="@color/red"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/activities"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="30"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="RESET PASSWORD"
        android:textColor="@color/manage_users_reset_pass"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Image 1 :- Correct Expanded Layout = First Time Expanded:-**
[image]

**Image 2 :- Incorrect Expanded Layout = Second Time Expanded:-**
[image]

Comment: don't use `layout_width="wrap_content"`when you're using `layout_weight`. Use `0dp`instead. Also, you should inflate your layout like that: `cInflator.inflate(R.layout.childrow, viewGroup, false);`

Comment: @DonL. your comment looks like an answer

Comment: @gunar well, it was a general hint. But you might be right.

Answer (score 1):

don't use `layout_width="wrap_content"` when you're using `layout_weight`. Use `layout_width="0dp"` instead.

Also, you should inflate your layout like that:

```
convertView = cInflator.inflate(R.layout.childrow, viewGroup, false);
```